# Can flag reviewers edit comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

I flagged Marcel Djamans comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/463828), because the formatting is broken. If you view the comment, you see that the code fragments are surrounded by `<code>` tags, but these are visible and the actual code fragments are displayed as normal text.

My flag got declined.

Is this because the reviewer was not able to edit the comment?
If so, shouldn't it be possible to do so for the reviewer?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting in comments is [limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) to very simply textual markdown. You can do any of the following:

- `**text**` or `__text__` = Bolding = **text**
- `*text*` or `_text_` = Italics = *text*
- ``text`\`  = Code Formatting = `text`
- `[example](http://example.com "title")` Inline links with title and text
- `http://example.com` plain old links

You can **not** format a code block that spans multiple lines. Comments are not meant for that purpose. If you need to add that much code either edit the question/answer or post your own answer.

---

The purpose of flags is **NOT** to have a moderator edit content. It is to draw attention to

- Rude or offensive comments
- Non constructive comments
- Obsolete comments
- Comments that are engaging in a discussion
- Other - Commonly used to inform moderators that an entire comment chain falls into one of the above so that you don't need to issue individual flags.

---

Moderators *can* edit a comment. They rarely will. It's not worth the time or effort to edit comments which are considered second class citizens. They should not contain information that is vital to answering a question. If such data does exist in the comments, it is better to edit those into an answer (so the information can be saved and formatted correctly) and then flag such a comment as Obsolete (because the data is now in the answer).

Comment: So in this case, it would be possible to format the code fragments via the option you mentioned. I am aware of that and I thought a mod could correct that, because it seems to me that maybe a migration caused the improper formatting. Correcting this, would not change the content